# array_map function defined with a class

Tags: php

I was reading through the code and came across this syntax:

```
$customerIDs = array_map(function(Customer $customer) { return $customer->id; }, $customers);
```

where `$customers` is the array.

My confusion is in trying to understand `function(Customer $customer)`. I see that `Customer` is a class, but what is `$customer` then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part:

```
function(Customer $customer) { return $customer->id; }
```

is an anonymous function. It's a "new" feature in PHP 5.3. It's pretty much equivalent to:

```
function someFunction(Customer $customer) {
    return $customer->id;
}

$customerIDs = array_map('someFunction', $customers);
```

As for the `Customer $customer` part, that's just a type-constrained argument. It throws an error if the argument passed is not of type `Customer`.

You can read more about anonymous functions [at the php.net documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).